# splitting list with regex

Tags: regex, split, jython

I am writing a test in Marathon and trying to get only one column of the JTable. 
The Content of it looks like this:

> [[**NEEDED_ITEM_1**, java.awt.Color[r=253,g=255,b=196], [ATTACHMENT], [all
>   levels], false, olololo@56fc12a9], [**NEEDED_ITEM_2**,
>   java.awt.Color[r=179,g=237,b=181], [ATTACHMENT], [2nd level, 3rd],
>   true, blablabla@cb331d80], [**NEEDED_ITEM_3**,
>   java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255], [ATTACHMENT], [1st level, 3rd level], false,
>   wwwww@2aedb772]]

So what I need is :
['NEEDED_ITEM_1','NEEDED_ITEM_2','NEEDED_ITEM_3']

I tried to convert the table content into a list by splitting it accordingly with the use of **regex**. However, I am having problems with finding the right expression to get this done.

If I do:

```
def get_my_table(my_list=[]):

    # Get table entries
    table = re.split('\], \[', get_p('myTable', 'Content')[2:-2])
    for lineIn_table in table:
        # Split up lines
        lineIn_table = re.split('\W+', lineIn_table)
        i = 1
        for columnIn_lineIn_table in lineIn_table:
            if i == 1:
                my_list.append(columnIn_lineIn_table)
            i += 1
    return my_list
```

as an output I only get:

['NEEDED_ITEM_1', 'MAIL_INCOMING', 'all', 'NEEDED_ITEM_2', 'MAIL_INCOMING', '2nd', 'NEEDED_ITEM_3', 'MAIL_INCOMING', '1st']

I thought of replacing the

> '\W'

in the second split by something like

> [@].+?\',\W\'\W[

which would split the list by this set of characters

> @cb331d80], [

However, this also does not give the correct result. I am not too good with regex expressions yet, so would appreciate any hints!

update, I modified it according to @Jodevan advice:

```
table = re.split('\[([\w]+),\s*(?:java)', get_p('myTable', 'Content')[2:-2])
        for lineIn_table in table:
            # Split up lines
            lineIn_table = re.split('\W+', lineIn_table)
            i = 1
            for columnIn_lineIn_table in lineIn_table:
                if i == 1:
                    my_list.append(columnIn_lineIn_table)
                i += 1
        return my_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this regex? `\[([\w]+),\s*(?:java)`
This relies on the fact that the next item is java.awt.color.
Then, in order to capture the NEEDED_ITEM_X you just have to get the first group.

Comment: this will not work, as on the first split, which is :
table = re.split('\], \[', get_p('myTable', 'Content')[2:-2])

Comment: You no longer need to split anything. Just build the full string and use the regex to extract the information you need.

Comment: I'm not following you. In your question you state the content looks like this: `[[NEEDED_ITEM_1, java.awt.Color[r=253,g=255,b=196], [ATTACHMENT], [all levels], false, olololo@56fc12a9], [NEEDED_ITEM_2, java.awt.Color[r=179,g=237,b=181], [ATTACHMENT], [2nd level, 3rd], true, blablabla@cb331d80], [NEEDED_ITEM_3, java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255], [ATTACHMENT], [1st level, 3rd level], false, wwwww@2aedb772]]`. If you use the the regex I suggested on this string, you'll get exactly what you need.

Comment: sorry, I just didn't finish writing the comment

Comment: what I m getting now is : ['Needed_item_1', 'java', '', 'Needed_item_2', 'java', '', 'Needed_item_3', 'java', '']

Comment: oh,do you mean there is no need to use split at all?

Comment: Correct, but please note the comment in my answer: "in order to capture the NEEDED_ITEM_X you just have to get the first group". I can't program in jython, but I'm pretty confident you can extract groups from a regex.

Comment: Exactly. Just apply the regex on the full string and you're all set. Remember to extract the groups. By the way, as soon as I posted the answer, I fixed a typo in the regex. Make sure you're using the correct one.

Comment: thank you for the advice. I will try doing it in suggested way, as for now I just made it return every third element of the list as a workaround.

Comment: I still suggest you to use groups, which will make your code cleaner and more correct. It's not that hard. Refer to item 7.2 in http://www.jython.org/docs/library/re.html. Also, flag the answer as valid if you think it solved your problem.

Comment: p.s. jython is not much different from python :) i m just writing the code intuitively